# Как прогнать данные формы через класс?

Tags: php

Есть форма

```html
<form method="post" action="Sanitize.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" placeholder="Enter product name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-input" name="image" placeholder="file">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Price">Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Enter average price">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Data">Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Date">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="author" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Класс `Sanitize`:

```
namespace ProductReview;

$obj = new Sanitize($_POST['name']);

class Sanitize
{
    private $input;

    public function __construct($input)
    {
        $this->input = $input;

    }


    public function sanitizeHtml()
    {
        return htmlentities($this->input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }



    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInput()
    {
        return $this->input;
    }

}

print_r( $obj->getInput());
```

`Action Sanitaize.php` это класс. Мне нужно загнать данные в конструктор и получить чистые данные методом getInput.

Comment: Нашел. Функция htmlsp... работает только с строками

Comment: А что на выходе вы хотите получить?

Comment: В каком плане чистые данные? Они и так в $_POST приходят как массив, к которому уже имеете доступ и можете обращаться к элементам массива через $_POST['elemen'] . Зачем вам лишние движения в виде непонятных функций. Объясните задачу и вам подскажут

Comment: Хотел проверку вынести в отдельный класс.